# Source of the name Zundel

Tags: names

I have a cousin named Zundel and I was wondering about the source of this name. Is it related to a Yiddish word? Does it come from a Hebrew word? Or is its source a secular name or word?

Answer (score 1):

Zondal's origin, as well as its use, is in the Yiddish language. The meaning of the name is 'little son'. The source of this name is Zundele.

http://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Zondal