# How did the name Zundel develop?

Tags: names

What is the source for the Jewish/Yiddish name Zundel/Zindel? Does it have an origin in Jewish religious traditions?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79282/source-of-the-name-zundel

Comment: As indicated above, you asked this question a few weeks ago. Please don't repost old questions.

Answer (score 4):

Zundel was not a uniquely Jewish name and does not per se have any connection to the Judaic faith.  Its origin is from Germanic languages:

> (also Zündel): from a diminutive of Zunder, a metonymic occupational name for a seller of kindling wood, from Middle High German zunder ‘tinder’.

from: http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=zundel

Alternatively, as a first name, Zundel is the diminutive of the Yiddish "zun" which means "son" (See, e.g., http://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Zundel ).

Answer (score 0):

As per Bris Avos  (8-33) and Sefer Ha'bris  (page 318, paragraph 22) the name Zundel was used as a name for a boy born to an unmarried girl. Apparently it means "the little sin" or something like that. So if your name is Zundel you probably have some skeletons in your closet (or in your ancestor's closet)   - if you go back far enough.

Comment: `Apparently it means "the little sin"` Or maybe it  a metonymic occupational name for a seller of kindling wood, from Middle High German zunder ‘tinder’ or perhaps it is the diminutive of the Yiddish "zun" which means "son".

Comment: @mevaqesh. Maybe. I was just pointing out what these seforim say.

Comment: Consider clarifying whether everything after 'Apparently' is what these works say, or your own conjecture.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Been a long time since I saw it inside so I can't be sure. Probably was not conjecture on my part.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Why would they specifically name a child born from an unmarried girl after a seller of kindling wood? Or the name "son"?

Comment: First of all they could've chosen any random name. Second, and more significantly, maybe that claim is totally bogus. It's not like any evidence was presented for it.